# Alarm Manager firing instantly

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I know this question has been asked many a times and answered too, I did check out a lot of posts and tried all of them but some how I'm still now having the trouble.

My code is like:

```
cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(CalendarUtils.getDateFromString(objScheduleDO.ScheduleStartTime, CalendarUtils.TIME_FORMAT));
    LogUtils.debug("Time",cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis() , pi);
```

I use RTC_WAKEUP it fires instantly and if i use ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP it doesn't fire at all.

And I'm sure the start time is never the current time, its always future time.

TIME_FORMAT is "hh:mm aa". And I have further verified that the time is correct, however when I tried to get cal.getTimeInMillis() through debug, I received a integer value instead of long, not sure whether Android Studio debug mode can give long value or not.

Please help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [AlarmManager set method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)),

> If the stated trigger time is in the past, the alarm will be triggered immediately.

Verify that your date is not past.